# How to cast a array of char in an integer which represent the ascii value of it?

Tags: c, ascii

I have a array of 4 chars and i need his ascii value in a single number.
For example in the array is `"joh0"`. The result should be in hex 0x6a726f00 or in int 111617776.
I use it in the function `ntohl(int x)`.

Comment: Are you sure 111617776 shouldn't 'read' 1785884416? As 111617776 equals 0x6a726f0, so this looks to me as if you simply forgot a trailing 0 when converting from hex to dec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like what you want this (possibly with the indices swapped):

```
char str[] = "joh0";

uint32_t val = (uint32_t)str[0]
             | (uint32_t)str[1] << 8
             | (uint32_t)str[2] << 16
             | (uint32_t)str[3] << 24;
```

But I don't know where you're getting 106111104048 from.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you don't have to first convert to `unsigned char`? I remember this being a big issue... I'd say `unsigned char * p = str;` and take it from there...

Comment: @KerrekSB: If the OP is using characters outside the standard ASCII range, then yes.

Comment: Ah, good catch on the "ASCII" requirement! :-) (I have a tendency to ignore that because almost nobody uses it in its true sense...)

Answer (score 0):

I presume that you're getting the sample number in this way:

```
Decimal:   106 111 104 048
Character: j   o   h   0
```

If that's the case, your number won't fit into a 32-bit integer value. You'll need to use a larger datatype like `uint64_t` or `unsigned long long`. You need something like the following:

```
const char str[] = "joh0";

unsigned long long result = ((unsigned long long)str[0])
                          + ((unsigned long long)str[1] * 1000LLU)
                          + ((unsigned long long)str[2] * 1000000LLU)
                          + ((unsigned long long)str[3] * 1000000000LLU);
```